# Backbone listenTo propertchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a ItemView that needs to listen to input and propertychange (for old IE versions).   The input event works fine, but propertychange doesn't seem to get bound

```
events:
 'input .textArea': 'someFunction'
 'propertychange .textArea': 'someFunction'
```

It does bind when I explicitly set it using `on` and `off` ex.

```
@textArea.on, 'input propertychange', someFunction
```

Is this just an event that can't be bound through the ItemView's `events`?

While I know the docs for `listenTo` can be used for the list of events on backbone.js.  Is there a way I can bind the two events through that method.  i.e

```
 @listenTo textArea, 'input properychange', someFunction
```

P.S I have tried `onpropertychange` in the `events` and it also does not work.  Also, it needs to be propertychange and not `keypress/keyup` etc events

Comment: (1) Does `propertychange` bubble? Remember that Backbone view events are handled through delegation. (2) `listenTo` is used for *Backbone* events, not *DOM* events.

Comment: Post the relevant code that binds the events?

Answer (score 0):

```
'input .textArea': 'someFunction'
```

Shouldn't that be

```
'input.textArea': 'someFunction'
```

instead? The selecto `'input .textArea'` means there is an element with the class name `textArea` inside an input. Probably not what you wanted...

Comment: It was just a bunch of pseudo code.  Not actually meant to convey the real issue that I was asking about.

Comment: Maybe if you post the relevant actual code, someone could find the problem?

Comment: The issue was with the 'propertychange' not the input. This ticket should be closed as the issue has been resolved